# UPDATE password in mySQLDatabase with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the password of the table 'nbk6_user'.

when the script is launched I get the error: "Fehler"

Am I doing the mysql_query right?

Can anybody help me please?

```
<?php
include 'conf.php';
$connection = mysql_connect("****", "****", "****");
mysql_select_db($datenbank);
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["name"]))
{
    die("Für diese Seite musst du dich zuerst anmelden!");
}
$name = $_SESSION["name"];

$pw1 = $_POST["pw1"];
$pw2 = $_POST["pw2"];

$pw1 = trim($pw1);
$pw2 = trim($pw2);

if($pw1 == "")
{
die("Kein Passwort gesetzt.");
}

if($pw1 == $pw2)
{
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password='$pw1', WHERE name='$name'");
    if(!$query)
    {   
        echo "Fehler";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein";
}
?>
```

Comment: remove the comma before `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a coma after SET and it's best to avoid inserting the variables inside a string, when dealing with MySQL queries (or any strings really, it's bad practice).

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password='".$pw1."' WHERE name='".$name."'");
if(!$query)
{   
    mysql_error();
    echo "Fehler";
}
```

if the changed query doesn't fix it [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) will explain where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

try see the error with mysql_error, but I think that u are putting "," after password='$pw1' I think so just try it

Answer (score 0):

Error in the query
use this

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password='".$pw1."' WHERE name='".$name."'");
```

Also read the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774315/change-password-code), this will brief you why you should not use mysql_* and use mysqli and PDO , taking care of sql injections.

Comment: then I get this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/.sites/26/site2378/web/nbk6/changepw.php on line 57

(line 57 is the mysql_query - line)

Comment: I think you are missing the quotes in the end of query, check it once

mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password="'.$pw1.'" WHERE name="'.$name.'" ")

Comment: -1. Changing string concatenation methods does NOTHING. `$x = "a$b"` is functionally identical to `$x = 'a' . $b`. All you've done is rearrange deck chairs on the titanic.

Comment: you do need quotes around string type variables in sql, so to add them you need to concatenate multiple strings in php.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dangling comma:

```
... SET password='$pw1', WHERE ...
                       ^---
```

Answer (score 0):

At first :

`session_start();` must be the first line in your code.

Then

```
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password='$pw1', WHERE name='$name'");
must be
$pw1=md5($pw1);
 $query = mysql_query("UPDATE nbk6_user SET password='$pw1' WHERE name='$name'");
```